# When to violate the single responsibility principle?

Tags: c++, coding-style, single-responsibility-principle, design-principles

How do you decide when and how to violate the [single responsability principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)?

For example, let's say I have a network camera with the following interface (interface kept stupid and "wrong" for simplicity):

```cpp
class Camera
{
  string user();
  void set_user(string user);

  string password();
  void set_password(string password);

  string url();
  void set_url(string url);

  image take_snapshot();

  bool reboot();
}
```

This looks natural, but it looks like the Camera class has 3 responsabilties: store metadata, take snapshot, reboot. Following the SRP, you could write it like this:

```cpp
class Camera
{
  string user();
  void set_user(string user);

  string password();
  void set_password(string password);

  string url();
  void set_url(string url);
}

image take_snapshot(camera c);
bool reboot_camera(camera c);
```

Here stuffs are neatly separated in terms of responsabilities, but now it looks very much like C with dumb structs and functions... which begs the question as to why we need OOP in the first place.

How do you balance between convenience and SRP?

[EDIT]

@stjin idea was shown as an answer by @John Zwinck

Comment: "When to violate the single responsability principle?" - rarely...

Comment: *This looks natural* not really: way to much getters/setters :] Maybe even so that once you fix that, you don't even need to ask this question anymore..

Comment: @stijn: this is an example... also I don't see how you can avoid this in some situations, except if you mean to code in C style with dumb structs and functions manipulating those.

Comment: no I don't mean that. There's also nothing 'dumb' about C structs. That is just how they are. And still very useful. I rather meant something like, for instance, creating a MetaData class and passing it to the Camera in it's constructor. That way, Camera has a single reponsability. And so does MetaData. Problem solved.

Comment: About your example, if Camera has one responsability, it is to take a snapshot.  Settings should be done by a (Camera-)settings class.

Comment: Using non-member functions where you conceptually want a member function doesn't separate the responsibilities; it just hides them. You'd separate them by defining separate classes (or functions, or interfaces, or...) for each responsibility, then combine them (by inheritance, or aggregate, or...) to build the set of responsibilities you need.

Comment: @stefaanv: I don't understand... why make a class if it only contains one function?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: interesting... care to build an example? say I need snapshot() / reboot() / set_config() / uptime()

Comment: @stijn: I added your idea as an example for people to discuss, feel free to add an answer with what you really meant and I'll remove the example.

Comment: @silex: it's from an object point of view: look at my camera, how lovely name I can give it -OR- look at my camera, how lovely pictures I can take...  I would guess that taking a snapshot requires more than 1 function, if only a reference to a real camera (as shown in John Zwick's answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write your example this way:

```
class Session
{
public:
  Session(string url, string user, string password);
};

class Camera
{
public:
  Camera(Session);

  image take_snapshot();
  bool reboot();
};
```

The main idea here is to separate authentication and session/endpoint definition (and perhaps connection) from the camera controls.  The class Camera now more closely models a real camera: it has something like a power button and a shutter button.  The virtualization of the camera is elsewhere, on its own.  This also makes it more obvious what to do if someone wants to make a USB session for a different camera, etc.

A secondary idea here is that objects are created with valid state from the beginning.  There is here no way to configure a Camera without a password for example, so calling take_snapshot() without credentials is simply not possible.  Of course the credentials may be invalid, but that can be checked by some method which might be called in one of the constructors.

As an aside, there is nothing wrong with free functions.  OOP is overrated, we all know it, and you shouldn't feel any need to apologize if free functions work in your use case.  Dumb structs can be better than pointless getter and setters--especially if you're not building a reusable library that has ABI compatibility requirements.

Comment: IMO, free functions *improve* object oriented programming because they add another level of accessibility. If a method only works on public members of an object and it's a class member itself, it will still have access to all private members. If it is a free function it has only access to what is needed to accomplish the task it is responsible for (ignore `friend`). Free functions in the same namespace can be considered part of the interface of a class.

Comment: @John Zwinck: okay, thanks for the example & rationale. Can you explain what comes to mind when deciding between the "free functions" approach and the "OOP" approach? I mean, the "free functions" alternative seems to be cleaner reguarding SRP almost all the time.

Comment: I mean, my real question is where to draw the line between the "OOP" convenient approach and "free functions" cleaner approach. Maybe something like "Use OOP when it maps nicely to a real world concept, use free functions when you need it to be more composable" ?

Comment: @Silex: This gets to be far too subjective.  It's a matter of taste in the end, you can make a decent system either way (no free functions or lots of them).  To some extent you just need to try to find your own way.  I'm not opposed to your suggestion to use OOP when it maps to a real-world concept, but do note that many people would point you to plenty of initially-appealing counterexamples (some of them would even claim OOP is entirely bad).

Comment: @JohnZwinck: okay, I guess this is not a solvable problem. I have my own way which tends to be "when it's convenient", but when I try to find a better rule I always end up with "free functions" style because it's the only one which you can't argue against... but then in some cases it's not convenient... and I wonder if a better rule can be found and questions like this are created. Thanks for the answer.